# change value in a one cell if another has value bigger than 0 in data grid view and vice versa

Tags: c#, datagridview, transactions, accounting

I want  the data in  data grid view to be changed in one cell "d" to 0 if the cell "c" have a value bigger than 0
And vice versa in c# language the data grid view is not pound to database in this two columon witch is text box.
2- i want this two text box to accept only numeric value .
Thank ....

Comment: Bind the grid to a `DataTable` or `List<MyClass>` such that the table column(s) are of an `int` type or the `MyClass` has `int` properties. If you do not use a `DataSource` for the grid… then your code is going to have to do all the work in converting and comparing the cell values.

Comment: Also, to allow only certain values to be typed into a `DataGridView` cell… you may find my answer at [How to enter letters in one column cell of the table and only numbers in the other column cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69660067/how-to-enter-letters-in-one-column-cell-of-the-table-and-only-numbers-in-the-oth) … helpful.